# Online SharePoint List View exceed threshold (5000), but still able to see all items

Tags: sorting, listview, office365, filtering, sharepoint-online

My SharePoint List View exceed threshold (5000), but I'm still able to see all the items. Even after I added a filter, and sort conditions.

I have tried adding a filter and sort conditions. I am expecting to see an error message :"The number of items in this list exceeds the list view threshold, which is 5000 items", instead I saw all the items which were 8800.

Answer (score 1):

You can store up to 30 million items or files in a list or library. However, when a list view shows more than 5000 items, you may run into a list view threshold error.

Reference: [Manage large lists and libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)

Comment: My list view shows more than 5000 items, and I didn't run into a list view threshold error. I'm still I'm able to see the whole 8800 items.

Answer (score 0):

On most occasions, you won't run into such issues. But when your records start exceeding 50,000 or more, there are high chances that you will experience this issue.

If you want to see the threshold issue, try creating a child list and adding a lookup column to the parent list with more than 5000 items. Also make sure that the Column you are using as lookup is not indexed in the Parent Column.